# Running an Automator task at night

Tags: macos, login, scheduled-tasks, automator, crontab

I've just created an **Automator** workflow and I'm using **crontab** to execute it at night.
The problem is that, after a while, the machine is going to sleep and a password is required (this is the intended behaviour).

Unfortunately, Automator seems to be unable to perform the task when the password is required. It works like a charm if the "password required" dialog is not displayed (before the sleep).

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: roberto, in the future please use the [osx] tag asking about software issues.  the [mac] tag should be used for Macintosh hardware.

Comment: Sure. I noticed your edit and I've applied it to my following question.

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be run at night?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an iCal task? I use this for a couple things and seems to work for me.